# JQuery/CSS Animate Sprite

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sprite image containing 4 different pictures. They are 520px in height. I would like to animate through them when either the left or right arrows are clicked. I'm unsure why it's not working.

Edited with changes and added css. still not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>FVRC Pics</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<h1> Fox Valley Runner Club</h1>

<div class="container">
   <div id="slider">
      <button id="leftArrow" class="fbtnFirst"/button>
      <button id="rightArrow" class="fbtnLast"/button>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="startApp">
        <ul>
            <li><a    href="http://itweb.fvtc.edu/200158947/Assign3/runners3.html">Start here!</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#leftArrow").click(function() {
         $("#slider").css("backgroundPostionX","600px");
    }); 
    $("#rightArrow").click(function() {
         $("#slider").css("backgroundPostionX","-600px");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
color: #0000ff;  /*blue*/
font-size: 44px;
padding-left: 10%;
}

.container {
max-height: 520px; 
background-color: #808080; /*grey*/ 
}

#leftArrow, #rightArrow {
display: inline-block;
width: 38px;
height: 50px;
}

#leftArrow {
position: relative;
/*top: 0;*/
top: 235px;
left: 2%;
width: 5%;
height: 50px;
background: url('../images/left_arrow.png') 0 0  no-repeat;
z-index: 10;
}

#rightArrow {
position: relative;
/*top: 0;*/
top: 235px;
left: 87.5%;
width: 5%;
height: 50px;
background: url('../images/right_arrow.png') bottom right no-repeat;
z-index: 10;
}

#slider {
position: relative;
height: 520px;
max-width: 792px;
margin: 0 auto;
/*background: url("../images/Animate-Sprite_520a.png") -0 0 no-repeat;*/
background-image: url('../images/Animate-Sprite_520a.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#startApp {
width: 235px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#startApp ul {
list-style-type:  none;
}

#startApp ul li a {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
width:  150px;
text-align: center;
background-color: steelblue;
border: 2px solid #808080;
color: white;
font-size: 32px;
```

Comment: `onclick(function(){` should be `on('click',function(){` .. and always keep eyes on  console for errors

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work but i don't know what is in your css files, i mean how you define your arrows

```js
  $("#leftArrow").click(function(){
    $("#slider").css("backgroundPostionX","400px"); 
  });
  
 $("#rightArrow").click(function(){
  $("#slider").css("backgroundPostionX","-400px");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Fox Valley Runner Club</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div id="slider">
   <button id="leftArrow" class="fbtnFirst"></button>
   <button id="rightArrow" class="fbtnLast"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="startApp">
  <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="http://itweb.fvtc.edu/200158947/Assign3/runners3.html">Start here!</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bigger issue is on the button element, you have onclick="move('left');" but the move function is never defined. You can take that out and let the even listener handle it instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>FVRC Pics</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<h1> Fox Valley Runner Club</h1>

<div class="container">
   <div id="slider">
  <button id="leftArrow" class="fbtnFirst"/button>
  <button id="rightArrow" class="fbtnLast"/button>
</div>

</div>
    <div id="startApp">
            <ul>
                <li><a    href="http://itweb.fvtc.edu/200158947/Assign3/runners3.html">Start here!</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/my_script.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#leftArrow").click(function(){
    $("#slider").css("backgroundPostionX","400px");
  }); 
  $("#rightArrow").click(function(){
    $("#slider").css("backgroundPostionX","-400px");
  });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```